# How do I load servlet-context.xml automatically?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm new to Spring Framework and am currently trying to figure out how to load a file called `servlet-context.xml` automatically at application start. This file contains a bean definition which I'd like to use using `@Autowired` in my application code.

**Note:** I know that I can do something like the following to manually load beans, but this doesn't work when you're using `@Autowired`:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

SomeObjectType x = (SomeObjectType)context.getBean("someObjectType");
```

I found this code sample from another tutorial which sort of tells how to load `servlet-context.xml`, but it was taken from a web application project which used MVC pattern. I don't have an web-app using MVC, so I don't think it applies to me:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The contents of my `servlet-context.xml` file are the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/Database"/>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

So what's the cleanest and simplest way to load `servlet-context.xml` file?

Comment: what do you mean by "this doesn't work when you're using @Autowired"  ?  autowired is an annotation which appears within the code and has nothing to do with beans definition file

Answer (score 0):

**you can uselistener to load context...**

```
 <listener>
         <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```